# Problemas con "TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON OBJECT"

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

En mi controlador defino una variable `$productoActual`, que llama al modelo con parámetro del id del proveedor, de modo a poder cargar la fila de la tabla proveedores en la variable, aca ocurre el error, la llamada se realiza y el parámetro se recibe en el modelo (lo se xq hice un `var_dump()` y me estira los datos de la fila q quiero) pero al hacer el `return()`del modelo al controlador este ya no recibe ningún dato (lo se porque al hacer el `var_dump()` de `$productoActual` me da como resultado `NULL`) alguien podría indicarme cual puede ser mi error? les comparto

EL CONTROLADOR

```
public function update_funcion()
{
    $idProveedor = $this->input->post("idProveedor");
    $nombre = $this->input->post("nombre");
    $descripcion = $this->input->post("descripcion");
    $telefono = $this->input->post("telefono");


    $proveedorActual = $this->Proveedores_models->getProveedor2_model($idProveedor);


    //$error = var_dump($proveedorActual);
    //return $error;
    if ($nombre == $proveedorActual["nombre_proveedores"])
    {
        $unique = '';
    }
    else
    {
        $unique = '|is_unique[proveedores.nombre_proveedores]';
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("nombre","Nombre","required".$unique);//se usa . para concatenar
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data = array
        (
            'nombre_proveedores' => strtoupper($nombre),
            'descripcion_proveedores' => strtoupper($descripcion),
            'telefono_proveedores' => $telefono
        );
        if ($this->Proveedores_models->update_model($idProveedor, $data))
        {
            redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/proveedores");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Hubo un problema al actualizar la informacion");
            redirect(base_url()."mantenimiento/proveedores/edit_proveedores/".$idProveedor);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->edit_funcion($idProveedor);
    }

}
```

Y EL MODELO

```
public function getProveedor2_model($idProveedor)
{
    $this->db->where("id_proveedores",$idProveedor);
    $resultado = $this->db->get("proveedores");

    return $resultado->row();
    //var_dump($resultado);
}
```

Espero poder contar con la ayuda de alguno. Desde ya muchísimas gracias.

Este el error completo

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property 'id_proveedores' of non-object
>
> Filename: proveedores/edit_proveedores.php
>
> Line Number: 29
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\application\views\admin\proveedores\edit_proveedores.php
>   Line: 29 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\application\controllers\mantenimiento\proveedores.php
>   Line: 73 Function: view
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\application\controllers\mantenimiento\proveedores.php
>   Line: 120 Function: edit_funcion
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ventas_ci\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>mantenimiento/proveedores/update_funcion" method="POST">
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $proveedor->id_proveedores;?>" name="id_proveedor">
                      <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty(form_error("nombre"))? 'has-error':''?>">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $proveedor->nombre_proveedores;?>">
                        <?php echo form_error("nombre", "<span class='help-block'>", "</span>");?> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="descripcion">Descripción: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" value="<?php echo $proveedor->descripcion_proveedores;?>">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="telefono">Teléfono: </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $proveedor->telefono_proveedores;?>">
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Guardar</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

EDIT_FUNCION

```
public function edit_funcion($id)
{
    $data = array
        (
            'proveedor' => $this->Proveedores_models->getProveedor2_model($id),
        );
    $this->load->view('layouts/header');
    $this->load->view('layouts/aside');
    $this->load->view('admin/proveedores/edit_proveedores', $data);
    $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
}
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el mensaje de error completo para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @RockoDev, actualice mi pregunta con el mensaje de error. espero puedas hecharle un ojo, saludos.

Comment: Ahí te marca que el error está en la linea 29 del archivo `proveedores/edit_proveedores.php`, puedes poner esa parte de tu código por favor?

Comment: ahora agregue el form donde se hace el llamado al controlador, Gracias x el seguimiento amigo, Saludos.

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $proveedor->id_proveedores;?>" name="id_proveedor">
esta seria la linea 29

Comment: ese error si identifico, porq ahí se deberia cargar lo que retorna del controlador, y como en el controlador no esta recibiendo nada del modelo, sale ese error..

Comment: el error me sale en el 'if()' del controlador que deberia tomar datos de la linea de arriba, y ahi me sale el "TRYING TO GET...."

Comment: Por lo que veo el problema está dentro del método `edit_funcion` de tu controlador.

Comment: el metodo edit_funcion lo que hace y es recibir el $idProveedor del registro (proveedor) y muestra los datos del registro asociados con esa ID, y x lo menos hasta ahora esta haciendo eso, luego al guardar la edicion es donde me da el error..

Comment: Con la respuesta que puse más abajo debería estar solucionado el problema.

Comment: Si tu pregunta está resuelta, no olvides marcar la solución. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo todo tu código, el problema puede estar en la primer linea del método `update_funcion`:

```
$idProveedor = $this->input->post("idProveedor");
```

Debe ser:

```
$idProveedor = $this->input->post("id_proveedor");
```

Comment: no cambio nada el error es el mismo, pero ya que estamos podrias quitarme una duda? en el caso de esa linea q me corregiste, '$idProveedor' que se define, pero el 'idProveedor' sale de donde?? por q no se define.

Comment: ahh, ya entendi, ese es el nombre del imput q estira del view vd?? que gran duda me sacaste!!

Comment: me funciono perfecto!! muchiiisimas Gracias.. en serio!!!

Comment: @ElvioFernandoBritosMoreno De nada. Así es, `$this->input->post` recibe el nombre del input y regresa el valor.